# Application-defined or object-defined error when using .formula

Tags: excel

I've been struggling to get a formula typed into a cell on a sheet. it's my activesheet (definitely).

Source is a file with full path. the sheet name is ... and lta_col_letter is the column letter I'm typing the formula into.

```
ActiveSheet.Range(lta_col_letter & 2).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('[" & Source & "]...'!$G:$G,MATCH(" & versionref_col_letter & "2,'[" & Source & "]...'!$B:$B,0))," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Help please!

EDIT:
Works when I added the missing [ brackets, but when it goes into the cell it adds the file name again after the sheet name and before the cell reference.It looks fine in a msgbox.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some opening square brackets around *source*.

```
 ActiveSheet.Range(lta_col_letter & 2).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('[" & source & "]...'!$G:$G,MATCH(" & versionref_col_letter & "2,'[" & source & "]...'!$B:$B,0)), text(,))"
```

To examine these types of errors, put a `'` before the opening `=` and run the procedure to put the formula into the cell as a string. Go to the worksheet and perform a visual examination and try to remove the `'`. Make corrections until you have a working formula then transfer the corrections to the VBA formula string.

Since it seems that you have used an open workbook to retrieve the workbook name into *source*, you might consider using the [Range.Address Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel) with External:=True to retrieve a fully punctuated external address.

```
dim sourceG as string, sourceB as string

sourceG = workbooks(source).worksheets("...").range("G:G").address(external:=true)
sourceB = workbooks(source).worksheets("...").range("B:B").address(external:=true)

ActiveSheet.Range(lta_col_letter & 2).Formula = _
  "=IFERROR(INDEX(" & sourceG & ", MATCH(" & versionref_col_letter & "2, " & sourceB 
 & ",0)), text(,))"
```

Comment: Good spot, but then when I add that the formula can't resolve. I seem to have the file name twice, so it starts like =IFERROR(INDEX('path\[file]...]file'!$G:$G,

Comment: That would depend on what is in *source* See the suggestion I added above. You can likely go back to where you assigned *source* and use the workbook reference for *sourceB* and *sourceG8.

Comment: btw, the `text(,)` is the same as `""` in a formula so in a VBA formula string you can use it instead of `""""` or `" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "`/

Comment: I get subscript out of range when setting the new sourceg and b.

Comment: What workbook holds the `...` worksheet? Do you have an object variable set to it?

Comment: ah, that's because you've gotten confused. source isn't active, the active workbook is where the formula is going. source never gets opened.

Comment: Is the source workbook even open or did you just assign a string to source?

Comment: Source is not open. it is a string file path. there is no need for it to be open

Comment: I've tried replacing the apostrophe where the issue is with char(39) but hasn't resolved it.

Comment: in VBA it's chr(39), not char(39)